# Javascript - cannot make static reference to non-static function 

Tags: javascript, arrays, static-methods

I am making a reference to the Javascript function splice() on an array and I get the error:

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static function splice()"

What's going on - how is this a static reference, aren't I referencing an instance of an Array class and its method - how is that static?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var queryPreds = new Array();
var queryObjs = new Array();    

function remFromQuery(predicate) {
    for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length;i++ ) { 
        if(queryPreds[i]==predicate)
        queryPreds.splice(i,1);
        queryObjs.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a Javascript engine message. It sounds like you're using an IDE that provides syntax checking and such. If you're using Eclipse, perhaps you're running into [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268066), which has been fairly recently fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I don't have a direct answer, but I can offer these notes...

- Could benefit from shorthand `$(function() { });` for document ready and `[]` for array literal
- arrayName in that function is not defined, is it defined elsewhere?
- You need to close your argument list you send to `$(document).ready()` with a closing parenthesis `)`
- Your indentation is confusing
- That `if` statement will only run the line immediately under it